# Spring Security and REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Security and I have a REST API for validating the username and password. So how to using REST API to authenticate username and password in Spring Security?

Comment: provide your efforts.

Comment: Hi, you need to show us what you've tried, so we don't duplicate any effort you've gone to. if you've gone to no effort - then we have to wonder why we should do it for you... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own custom AuthenticationProvider, you'll have chance to override the authenticate(Authentication auth) method. Then register your provider bean with Spring Security configuration, like below

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Can I use UserDetailsService for creating microservice for authentication?